# Javascript onclick or jquery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a javascript or jquery i am not sure which one that when i press the fift radio buton and then click next to send me to another html page.
If you can give me an example i would be grateful.
P.S sorry for my bad english:D
here is a example

```
</head>

<body>

<p>please select a year</p>
<form action="picture2.html">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2years">0-2 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2years">3-5 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2years">6-10 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2years">More than 10 years<br>
<input type="radio" id="demo" name="answer" value="terminate">i have 20 years (if this is selected go to another html page)<br>
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction" value="Next">
</form>


<script>
$(function(){
  $("input:radio:fifth").click(myFunction();
});

function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("button").onclick="window.location.href='picture2.html'";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: next means next button in your english right

Comment: yes next button, i tried... but i am stuck

Comment: Even your question is not clear and you gave no code either, try first and if stuck then come with code.

Comment: ok  do u have html for radio button please provide it is helpful for our team

Comment: use `$("#demo").click(myFunction);` and In you function just use `window.location.href='picture2.html'`

Comment: Here is workind fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5s9As/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the link given below:

http://jsfiddle.net/u8jD9/

http://jsfiddle.net/nnEny/

```
 if ($('#rdo1').is(':checked')) {
                    window.location.replace("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
                }
                else if ($('#rdo2').is(':checked')) {
                    window.location.replace("http://www.exchange.com");
                }
```